# How can i use ffmpeg to compress a .mp4 ( h264 ) to a smaller size without quality loss?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, compression, resize2fs

Hello i am kinda new with ffmpeg and learning everyday, i am now looking for on how i can compress a video in a smaller size. since i have some 1920x1080 mp4 files with a rediculous high size.

For example, take this .mp4 i got. it is in;

**duration**: 22 minutes and 31 seconds long (**00:22:31**).

**Resolution** 1920x1080

**Frames per second** 30fps

This file is **came out of export** from a editting software as **3,85Gb** wich is to big in my oppinion.
*

I need some help with how i could reduse this file size when using ffmpeg. I have tryed to find some tips and i've tryed last night this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mp4" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac -b:a 128k "target.mp4"
```

i had found it somewhere on youtube with saying there would be no quality loss, but unfortunately it had, and a little to much.

So who could help me further? I would love to get some help.

Greats sam.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg/38380#38380

Comment: This has a windows tag. Why?